# is well-formed html5 loaded faster than a crappy one?

Tags: html, browser, xhtml

html5 is not as strict as xml so even this crappy file gets validated by the w3c html5 [validator](https://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>crappy html5</title>
<div class=dummy>
<h1>crappy html5</h1>
<p class=noclosetag>HTML5 is awesome
<ol class=navigator>
<li><a href=/>index</a>
<li><a href=/user>user</a>
<li><a href=/rss>rss</a>
</ol>
</div>
```

if the rule is permissive then some lazy programmer might save some work by writing crappy files; however, i am wondering **whether this will cause noticeable performance issues** because the browser needs to correct mistakes on a crappy page; i have not done a test yet, partly because i do not know what would be a fair and thorough test for such things;

Comment: So define crappiness. If it is well-formed HTML, like in this example, is it still crappy? I would have expected the validator to complain about unquoted `/` in an attribute  value though, to be honest. An older [SGML definition of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) didn't mention slashes as being able to go unquoted.

Comment: @MrLister informally crappiness is what makes it more complicated to correctly parse and understand the semantics of an html document; an example is unclosed tags; you could say you still know how to correctly generate dom tree for such document because your html knowledge is as good as a parser, but this is unlikely to be true for less experts; formally the boundary between crappiness and non-crappiness is whether the document can be successfully parsed by a validator; so you could safely say the above document is non-crappy in that sense, but that is not what this question is talking about;

Comment: Your concern is valid in regards to *search engines*. Every parser is going to be different and often I have come across search engines visiting an HTTP 404 because either a website did not properly parse (or validate) a URL (e.g. http://example.com/www.i-dont-know-how-to-link). My recommendation is to serve HTML5 as XML (application/xhtml+xml) and to ensure that simple things be validated. Even easier since in example `input` elements now support `type="url"` though all client data should always be validated. Proper/strict code has many benefits that compound the time saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The HTML parser really doesn't care about the crappiness of the HTML, and "correcting mistakes" is not how it works. It simply processes each byte it sees and constructs the DOM accordingly.

Although the parser *may* report on parse errors in the console, your sample doesn't contain any parse errors anyway. Either way, it'll have zero effect on performance.

If you want to study how the parser works, it's all described in [section 8 of the HTML5 spec](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html)

Comment: That said, a source like this may load marginally faster, because there's fewer bytes to transfer. Not sure how much of an impact that would have though.